# Is there a way to require a property via abstract base class without requiring an explicit getter

Tags: python

I would like to enforce that subclasses have an attribute without the clutter of getters. I don't really see the need to have the getter code if in python it is already a public attribute.

I checked [PEP-3119](https://peps.python.org/pep-3119/), which has little to say about attributes/properties in ABC other than that they work via the method shown below (although using the 3.3+ deprecated @abstractproperty decorator) and the python docs are largely a subset copy/paste of the PEP + minor updates for the 3.3+ deprecations.

I know I can just implement an `__init__` with the required properties, but this still requires the subclass to call the `super().__init__` as there's still no checking of the presence of the attributes.

I understand the most likely reason the getter is required is because it is still decorated with @abstractmethod so the machinery looks for the method and doesn't necessarily care that it is also a property, but I would like to know if there is a (pythonic) way to enforce with ABC without the getter.

```
import abc

class MyABCClass(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    
    # a property written as a getter, registered as an abstract method - need to override
    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def x(self):
        pass
    
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def some_method(self):
        pass

    
class MySubClass(MyABCClass):
    def __init__(self, x=0):
        self.x = x # this is all I really want to require, not necessarily in the __init__ method
        
    # I'd prefer not to have this method, but if omitted: 
    # TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class MySubClass with abstract method x
    def x(self):
        return self.x

    def some_method(self):
        ...
```

Comment: I know you probably realize this and are just curious, but just in case It’ I’d like to point out that by definition it would not be good code, a good language should strive to make such a thing impossible.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "good code"/"good language" in this context? Python has all attributes public and they explicitly included enforcement via the @abstractproperty decorator in the PEP so clearly someone thought it was "good code" for the language, but I also know adding a bunch of getters/setters/deleters qualifies to many people as a "code smell" and yet Python included decorators to do just that. I'm not challenging your assertion, just want to know the context. If the "good code" version is to do the getters/setters/deleters explicitly per the ABC module, I'm fine with that.

Comment: Enforcing a specific implementation style in another class is tight binding between the classes.  Using properties at all means that you are asking another class for it's information instead of asking it to do something for you.  Allowing settable properties makes your class mutable which is something to avoid if you can.  None of it is horrible, but most doesn't smell great.  Just because a language codifies bad design doesn't make it good, properties are always a red flag for me, in particular writable ones.